# Pycharm Pro and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, python, ide

I have installed Pycharm on Ubuntu 14.04 using [this](http://www.thornstrom.net/how-to/linux/ubuntu-and-pycharm/) useful guide. However the installation is the Community one and I'd like to get the Pro version for which I have a licence.

Is there any way to upgrade or is it a case of uninstall and then follow [this](http://www.bonusbits.com/main/HowTo%3aInstall_PyCharm_on_Ubuntu)
guide which is much more hassle, but compatible with the download available at the Jetbrains site.

Comment: I installed both, downloaded directly from the site. Extracted and ran without any problems.  If you have projects, note where they are stored.  In my migration, everything just worked ; I had only a very small project in ~`/PycharmProjects`.  (Also, I had community and pro extracted to different directories.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like yourself, I'm a PyCharm Pro user - I gained this through my opensource developments.

The PyCharm Pro download is much larger than the community edition - this indicates that the extras bundled with Pro don't exist in the community edition.  Hence - to gain the benefit of the Pro, you basically uninstall the community and reinstall the new version.

Its tidier to do it this way rather than untar'ing over the community install.

The only minor gotcha was that my local community installed edition created an icon desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` - this conflicted with the Pro version.  Hence, you'll need to remove the local file first before the Pro version is recognised.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to follow any guide, specially not the complicated one. You just need to follow this steps:

1. Install java, Oracle java if possible.
2. Download and extract the version from the PyCharm site
3. Extract the file, run pycharm.sh from the bin folder
4. Optional, go to menu **Tools > Create Desktop Entry** to add it to your system menus.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to install both versions but it will be counter productive sync your user defined settings from one to other.

Before you proceed further backup your settings. I am going to describe instructions for uninstalling Pycharm Community edition. You can also use this to remove Pycharm Professional edition.

Suppose you have pycharm Community installed at `/home/<user>/ide/`.
Use command this command `rm -r ~/ide/pycharm-2016.3.2` to remove it.

You should also remove by these entries by using command `rm -r`. This contains your configs/license files for Pycharm.

```
rm -r ~/.PyCharm2016.3
rm ~/.gnome/apps/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop
rm -r ~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains/pycharm
rm ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop
```

Use `sudo updatedb && locate pycharm` to check whether other pycharm files are still left. If you any files that has `pycharm` in the name which is useful to you than don't delete them.

NOTE: If `rm -r` doesn't work use `sudo rm -r`.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you’re on Ubuntu 16.04 or later and PyCharm is installed using `snap package` then you could remove it by running following commands:

```
sudo snap remove [pycharm-professional|pycharm-community]
rm -rf ~/.PyCharm2017.3
rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains/pycharm/
```

replace `.PyCharm2017.3` with your installed version.